# How to add a progress bar in tkinter using python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have almost 100 images in a nano pi photo folder. I am transferring these images into a Windows system using `paramiko`. For this, I have created a GUI, using Python, where I want to select the folder and one download button. Once I have clicked the download button, it should also update a progress bar as all the images are transferred from Linux to Windows.

```
# import librery for corresponding code
import os
import shutil
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import paramiko
from scp import SCPClient
import time
import threading


# initialize gui interface
root=Tk()
root.geometry("510x200")
root.title("GEOTAG PICTURE MANEGER")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.configure(bg="#ac75c9")
root.wm_iconbitmap(r'D:\EdallSystem\NPNT_RELT\client.ico')     


# select the folder that u want to select for past the pic
global folder_selected, path

def getFolderPath():

    global folder_selected
    folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()
    #print(folder_selected)
    folderPath.set(folder_selected)



folderPath = StringVar()
a = Label(root ,text="Chose Folder :")
#a.grid(row=0,column = 0)
a.place(x=20,y=50)
E = Entry(root,textvariable=folderPath,width="60")
E.grid(row=0,column=1)
E.place(x=100,y=50)
btnFind = ttk.Button(root, text="Browse Folder",command=lambda: background(getFolderPath, ()))
btnFind.grid(row=0,column=3)
btnFind.place(x=420,y=50)

# download the pic from root directory to the local system
# it will search the file from root path i.e  remote_images_path = '/root/photo/photo/'
# and paste it to the local folder 

def down():       
    try:
        global folder_selected,path

        files = []
        remote_images_path = '/root/photo/photo/'
        path=folder_selected
        path=path.replace('/', '\\\\')+'\\\\'
        #print(path)

        local_path = path  #"D:\\EdallSystem\\socket_pro\\photo\\folder_selected\\"
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(hostname = "192.168.2.199", username = "root",password='fa')
        ftp = ssh.open_sftp()

        scp = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport())

        for i in ftp.listdir(remote_images_path):
            start = time.time()
            #lstatout=str(ftp.lstat(i)).split()[0]
            #if 'd' in lstatout: 
                #print (i, 'is a directory')
            files.append(i)

        for file in files:

            file_remote = remote_images_path + file
            file_local = local_path + file

            print (file_remote + '>>>'*2 + file_local)

            scp.get(file_remote, file_local)
            done = time.time()
            elapsed = done - start

        print("Time taken in Sec:",elapsed)


        scp.close()
        ssh.close()

    except:
        messagebox.showinfo(" ", "No Picture Selected")
        #ttk.level(root,text='No pic')



def background(func, args):
    th = threading.Thread(target=func, args=args)
    th.start()

dwn=ttk.Button(root,text="Download",width='25',command=lambda: background(down, ()))
dwn.place(x=190,y=120)

root.mainloop()
```

I want to add a progress bar to the GUI, but I don't know how. Please help me.

Comment: @Nick thank you for your effort . please help me i want to learn new thinks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this bit of code on the Tkinter progress bar.

```
# importing tkinter module 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

# creating tkinter window 
root = Tk() 

# Progress bar widget 
progress = Progressbar(root, orient = HORIZONTAL, 
              length = 100, mode = 'determinate') 

# Function responsible for the updation 
# of the progress bar value 
def bar(): 
    import time 
    progress['value'] = 20
    root.update_idletasks() 
    time.sleep(1) 

    progress['value'] = 40
    root.update_idletasks() 
    time.sleep(1) 

    progress['value'] = 50
    root.update_idletasks() 
    time.sleep(1) 

    progress['value'] = 60
    root.update_idletasks() 
    time.sleep(1) 

    progress['value'] = 80
    root.update_idletasks() 
    time.sleep(1) 
    progress['value'] = 100

progress.pack(pady = 10) 

# This button will initialize 
# the progress bar 
Button(root, text = 'Start', command = bar).pack(pady = 10) 


mainloop()
```